# Would [past habit]

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Can we omit using "would" again if there are several actions in a sentence. 
Ex. "In the first place upon coming home he would lock himself in his room, [would] grab a book and [would] read it for hours."

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes the subsequent uses of "would" can be omitted in such a case. This means that the sentence says that what he "would do" is a sequence o set of actions, considered as a unit grammatically speaking.

In fact, it is my view that the sentence reads better and  more naturally without the repeated use of "would".